# Im getting an error starting a new deployd server

Tags: angularjs, deployd

Im using deployd to build my angularjs app.
And I do the following:

```
> dpd create sportsstore

> cd sportsstore 

> dpd –p 5500 app.dpd
```

but when then i get this error:

Failed to start MongoDB (Make sure 'mongod' are in your $PATH or use dpd --mongod option. Ref: http://docs.deployd.com/docs/basics/cli.html)

But i do have MongoDB in the $PATH, but it isnt wornking...

Comment: Are you sure `mongod` is in your $PATH? What does `which mongod` say?

Comment: Yhea i do https://prnt.sc/s08qhu @vrdrv